# How to Establish an Audio Connection with FreeSWITCH that comes along with Big Blue Button via SIP.js?

Tags: webrtc, sip, freeswitch, bigbluebutton

I am trying to establish an audio connection with the freeswitch that sits in the big blue button server. Although iam providing valid sip credentials, along with TURN/STUN server credentials the connection gets timed out while trying to register the user agent.

I am able to establish a websocket connection with the server so network traversal and authentication isn't exactly the issue.

Here is how my user agent looks like:
this.userAgent=new UserAgent({        uri:UserAgent.makeURI(`sip:${encodeURIComponent(this.authorizationUsername)}@${this.hostname}`),
transportOptions: {
server: `${(this.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://')}${this.hostname}/ws?sessionToken=${token}`,
connectionTimeout: this.USER_AGENT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS,
keepAliveInterval: this.WEBSOCKET_KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL,
keepAliveDebounce: this.WEBSOCKET_KEEP_ALIVE_DEBOUNCE,
traceSip: true,
},
sessionDescriptionHandlerFactoryOptions: {
peerConnectionConfiguration: {
iceServers,
sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan',
iceTransportPolicy: 'relay',
},
},
displayName: this.authorizationUsername,
authorizationPassword: this.authorizationPassword,
authorizationUsername: this.authorizationUsername,
});

I would be grateful if anyone has a solution to this issue, or if anyone can refer me to a correct implementation for the same.